# Sorting multi-dimensional array by count of subarray

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the array like this:

```
Array
(
  [28748] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uid] => 28748
        [status] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [29163] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 29163
                        [status] => 1
                    )

            )

    )

[28708] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uid] => 28708
        [status] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [27104] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 27104
                        [status] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [28250] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28250
                                        [status] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [29448] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 29448
                        [status] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [28528] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28528
                                        [status] => 1
                                    )

                                [28329] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28329
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [28533] => stdClass Object
                                                   (
                                                  [uid] => 28533
                                                  [status] => 1
                                               )
                                    )

                                [26548] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 26548
                                        [status] => 1
                                     )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

And I want to sort the array by the count of sub array, so the no of children is greater will come first. The level of dimension is unlimited. In my case I want to become this array:

```
Array
(

[28708] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uid] => 28708
        [status] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [29448] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 29448
                        [status] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (

                                [28329] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28329
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [28533] => stdClass Object
                                                   (
                                                  [uid] => 28533
                                                  [status] => 1
                                               )
                                    )

                                [28528] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28528
                                        [status] => 1
                                    )

                                [26548] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 26548
                                        [status] => 1
                                     )

                            )

                    )

                    [27104] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 27104
                        [status] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [28250] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28250
                                        [status] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[28748] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uid] => 28748
        [status] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [29163] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 29163
                        [status] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Here is the new array that i am checking:

```
Array
(
 [27104] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uid] => 27104
        [status] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
            [28250] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 28250
                        [status] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [28839] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28839
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [27102] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [uid] => 27102
                                                        [status] => 1
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )

                [26551] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 26551
                        [status] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [25368] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 25368
                                        [status] => 1
                                    )                            
                            )
                    )
            )
    )

[28708] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uid] => 28708
        [status] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [29448] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 29448
                        [status] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [28528] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28528
                                        [status] => 1
                                    )

                                [28329] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28329
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [28654] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [uid] => 28654
                                                        [status] => 1
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )

                                [26548] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 26548
                                        [status] => 1
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )

[28748] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uid] => 28748
        [status] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [28838] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 28838
                        [status] => 1 
                    )

                [28685] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 28685
                        [status] => 1
                    )

                [29163] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 29163
                        [status] => 1
                    )
            )
    )
  )
```

and after using "sortByNumChildren($data)" i'm getting

```
  Array
 (
  [28748] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uid] => 28748
        [status] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [29163] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 29163
                        [status] => 1
                    )

                [28685] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 28685
                        [status] => 1
                    )

                [28838] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 28838
                        [status] => 1
                    )
            )
    )

[28708] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uid] => 28708
        [status] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [29448] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 29448
                        [status] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [26548] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 26548
                                        [status] => 1
                                    )

                                [28329] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28329
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [28654] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [uid] => 28654
                                                        [status] => 1
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                                [28528] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28528
                                        [status] => 1
                                    )
                           )
                    )
            )
    )

[27104] => stdClass Object
    (
        [uid] => 27104
        [status] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [26551] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 26551
                        [status] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [25368] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 25368
                                        [status] => 1
                                    )
                            )
                    )

                [28250] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [uid] => 28250
                        [status] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [28839] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 28839
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [27102] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [uid] => 27102
                                                        [status] => 1
                                                    )

                                            )
                                    )
                           )
                    )
            )
    )
```

)

and this looks incorrect as this is not sorted by all children's count.
sorting should be according to the number of all descendants.

Please check this.

Comment: take a look at this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) is more appropriate in this case, as it maintains the original (numerical) keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function that sorts each level with [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php):

```
function sortByNumChildren(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$obj) {
        if (isset($obj->children)) sortByNumChildren($obj->children);
    }
    uasort($array, function ($a, $b) { 
        if (!isset($a->children)) return 1;
        if (!isset($b->children)) return -1;
        return count($b->children) - count($a->children);
    });
}
```

Call this function as follows:

```
sortByNumChildren($data);
```

See it run, together with output, on [eval.in](https://eval.in/556406)

This code will sort by number of (immediate) children. See below for sorting on number of descendants.

#### Code for sorting by number of *all* descendants

As requested here is an alternative piece of code which sorts the nested array by number of descendants, so also counting grandchildren and their children, etc.:

```
function sortByNumChildren(&$array) {
    $childCounts = array();
    foreach ($array as &$obj) {
        $childCounts[$obj->uid] = isset($obj->children) ? 
                sortByNumChildren($obj->children) : 0;
    }
    uasort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($childCounts) { 
        return $childCounts[$b->uid] - $childCounts[$a->uid];
    });
    return count($array) + array_sum($childCounts);
}
```

Call this function as follows:

```
sortByNumChildren($data);
```

See it run, together with output, on [eval.in](https://eval.in/556930)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but i think one thing i missed here

if the total number of children is greater that array will come first.

Comment: Ah, so you don't want to sort by the number of immediate children, but the number of all children at any level in the hierarchy below the node? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: If not, then I don't understand your comment. The code I provided will put arrays first that have the most (direct) children.

Comment: "Ah, so you don't want to sort by the number of immediate children, but the number of all children at any level in the hierarchy below the node? Do I understand correctly? "


  

Yes you are correct...I want the output this way

Comment: Added a section in my answer for sorting by number of descendants (instead of only by direct children).

Comment: Thank you so much for this...
Just one thing if there are no children element then it should be at bottom because count is none.

Comment: True, but I thought to have covered that. Can you give an example (edit your question) where you get the wrong order with this?

Comment: Can you give some feed-back?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
and sorry i couldn't give you the feedback but here is the feedback
i have checked this and there is some issue with it. i have edited my question and added a new array in which i'm getting issue. Please check this.

thanks

Comment: I think you did not use the function I provided for sorting by the count of all descendants. I get a correct result with the data you added to your question. See this [eval.in](https://eval.in/560658).

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you give some feed-back?

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for your answer @trincot .

but i think one thing i missed here
if the total number of children is greater then that array will come first.

As mentioned in my array suppose i have added 2 more elements in the first sub array likewise

```
28748 => stdClass Object

(
    [uid] => 28748
    [status] => 1
    [children] => Array
        (
            [29163] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uid] => 29163
                    [status] => 1
                ) 
              [29173] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uid] => 29173
                    [status] => 1
                )
               [29174] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uid] => 29174
                    [status] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

total no of children in first sub array = 3

total no of children in second sub array = 7

but total no of children(counting inner children as well) in the second sub array is greater so the second sub array will come first and this shold work same as in the inner part as well.

Please look into this.

Comment: I covered this in my answer. Please also move this into your question where it belongs.

Comment: Can you delete this "answer"? It does not belong here. If still needed, please edit your question and add it there.